# How to replaceFirst in Kotlit by regex?

Tags: kotlin

I have a string and expect it to be changed when calling `replaceFirst` but it always is the same, not changed.

```
"there are 400 pictures".replaceFirst(" [0-9]{3}", " a lot of ")
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the overload of `replaceFirst` that takes a `String`, which replaces the first occurrence of that exact string. Obviously, " [0-9]{3} " does not occur in your string.

To use regex, create a [`Regex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/) object and pass it to `replaceFirst`. This will call the overload that takes a `Regex`:

```
val replaced = "there are 400 pictures".replaceFirst(Regex(" [0-9]{3} "), " a lot of ")
println(replaced) // there are a lot of pictures
```

See all the overloads [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace-first.html).